# Cannot connect to mysql on docker

Tags: mysql, docker

This is my service definition:

```
version: "3"
services:
  rabbit:
    image: rabbitmq:management
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
        #  - "15672:15672"
  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: eventstore
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "*"
```

If I connect to mysql from the docker, and run this:

```
SELECT host, user FROM mysql.user;
```

I get:

```
+-----------+------------------+
| host      | user             |
+-----------+------------------+
| %         | root             |
| localhost | mysql.infoschema |
| localhost | mysql.session    |
| localhost | mysql.sys        |
| localhost | root             |
+-----------+------------------+
```

So it should be fine. Then if I run:

```
mysqld --verbose --help | grep bind-address
```

I have:

```
mysqld --verbose --help | grep bind-address
2018-10-25T14:40:08.820014Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
  --bind-address=name IP address to bind to.
  --mysqlx-bind-address[=name] 
bind-address                                                 0.0.0.0
mysqlx-bind-address                                          *
```

This also should be fine.
Running `netcat 172.30.0.3 3306` (ip address get through docker inspect), I have a response.
But still, this gives me an error:

```
mysql -u root 172.30.0.3 -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: You need expose the port for mysql if try access from host.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the comment. I'm using its port on its ip, as you can see I can connect to it with netcat so I don't need to expose anything I think

Comment: I've just tried it, with: ` expose:- "3306"` in the docker-compose but still didn't work. Thanks anyway for the shot!

Comment: I think you have to bind 3306:3306 to connect from host with "localhost" name, with a export port you can connect to your container with the container IP

Comment: I want to connect to the MySQL with its IP

Comment: The Docker-internal IP addresses are basically useless.  Use `docker run -p xxxx:3306` to publish a port on the host, and then use your physical host’s name and that port number.

Comment: The problem is that I want to access mysql from another container on the same network - not my physical host. So I don't need/want to publish the port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this format:

```
mysql -u {username} -p {password} -h {remote server ip or name} -P {port}
```

and make sure that the port is available on that IP.

```
mysql -u root -p -h 172.30.0.3 -P 3306
```